# How to upload an API built with nodejs, Express, MySQL to Cpanel shared host

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, cpanel, nodemon

So as far as I know I need to ignore the node_modules folder

and create a new database in PHPMyAdmin in Cpanel and place the credentials in the .env file

then upload the zip file to the folder of the subdomain then extract it

export the database from local and import from Cpanel

create a new nodejs application in Cpanel as follow:

[image]

run npm install

and when I test it using postman as follows:

Method: POST
URL: {url}/createUser
payload: json

I receive: 503 Service Unavailable

but when I change the URL to local it works

this is my project structure:

[image]

and this is my package.json:

```
{
"name": "",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
"bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
"express": "^4.18.2",
"jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
"mysql": "^2.18.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
"dotenv": "^16.0.3",
"nodemon": "^2.0.20"
}
}
```

.env file:

```
DB_HOST = 127.0.0.1
DB_USER = {{user}} <- private
DB_PASSWORD = {{password}} <- private
DB_DATABASE = {{database}} <- private
DB_PORT = 3306
PORT = 3000
```

In localhost, I'm using this command to run the API: nodemon dbServer

so what seems to be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

First Please Remove `.env` File From Your Project

And Copy and Paste all variable with value on text editor

and Then Click on add Environment Variable in cPanel

After That Fill Each `Variable and Value` one By One

And Please Also Add this code in package.json file

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "nodemon app.js",
  "start": "node app.js"
},
```

Then Start Your App

Please, Don't Forget To Select Script in `Run JS Script` and Chose Option Start

Now Your App Will Be Install and Work on That Particular Domain

Comment: i removed .env file and placed all in node application and add the code to package.json still same issue with postman even after i run npm install again and reload the application

Comment: did you add environment variable into cPanel Environment Variable Field And Please Check Above Answer I Did Update ther

Comment: it should be "nodemon app.js" or "nodemon dbServer.js" because i need to run dbServer.js not app.js

Comment: then it should be nodemon dbServer.js remember nodemon will be use full for testing environment only not for production environment so please use start node dbServer.js